# Can elasticsearch-setup-passwords be auto-filled with a bash script?

Tags: bash, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch and Kibana server running on a single EC2 instance which was setup using a bash script. At the moment of loading credentials I used elasticsearch-setup-passwords tool which is interactive, so I had to manually add credentials. I know I could have used the parameter 'auto' but I need to used the credentials specified in my bash file   so that option does not work as it will load random credentials. Is there a way to automate it with bash?

Comment: _"`-b, --batch`: If enabled, runs the change password process without prompting the user."_ Did you try it? something like `printf %s mypassword | elasticsearch-setup-passwords -b ...` might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Fravadona mentioned above, take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/setup-passwords.html#setup-passwords-parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, I managed to solve it using your references.

Comment: Could you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I fully automated the ES 7.10.2 and 7.16.3 deployments.
My script will even download the needed files from the web if it cannot find them locally, assuming the server has access to artifacts.elastic.co

I hope that someone can use this code, as it took me many stressful hours to figure out the hard bits.

My script is a lot more verbose than below, but you'll get the gist of what you need from the lines:

```
Write-Output "Generating ES CA certificate"
echo ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_CA} | & cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-certutil ca -s --out ${ELASTICSEARCH_PATH_CERTIFICATES_DIRECTORY}\elastic-stack-ca.p12"
Start-Sleep 2

Write-Output "Creating ES keystore" 
echo ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KEYSTORE} | & cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-keystore create -s"
Start-Sleep 2

Write-Output "Adding secure passwords to ES keystore" 
echo ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KEYSTORE} | & cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-keystore add xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.secure_password"
echo ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KEYSTORE} | & cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-keystore add xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.secure_password"
echo ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KEYSTORE} | & cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-keystore add xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password"
echo ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KEYSTORE} | & cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-keystore add xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password"
echo ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KEYSTORE} | & cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-keystore add bootstrap.password"

Write-Output "Creating ES certs file"
cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-certutil cert -s --ca-pass ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_CA} --ca ${ELASTICSEARCH_PATH_CERTIFICATES_DIRECTORY}\elastic-stack-ca.p12 --out ${ELASTICSEARCH_PATH_CERTIFICATES_DIRECTORY}\elastic-certificates.p12 --pass ${ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_CA} "
Start-Sleep 2

Write-Output "Setting user passwords"
#Yes, the lines are silly, but whatever. This must be left hugging and no space/tabs.  
#IF THERE ARE SPACES TO EITHER SIDE OF THE VARIABLES BELOW -- DELETE THEM!
echo "y
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_APM_SYSTEM
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_APM_SYSTEM
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KIBANA_SYSTEM
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KIBANA_SYSTEM
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KIBANA
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_KIBANA
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_LOGSTASH_SYSTEM
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_LOGSTASH_SYSTEM
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_BEATS_SYSTEM
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_BEATS_SYSTEM
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_REMOTE_MONITORING_USER
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_REMOTE_MONITORING_USER
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_ELASTIC
$ELASTICSEARCH_XPACK_PASSWORD_ELASTIC
"| & cmd /c "${ELASTICSEARCH_DIRECTORY_LOCATION}\bin\elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive" *>$null 2>&1
```